# Is there any case where %p format specifier will not print address in 0x.. format

Tags: c, pointers, stdio, format-specifiers, implementation-defined-behavior

In C, I am reading an address from console and storing it in a variable.
I need to log the address in hex (0x...) format.

I have 2 options:

1. %p
2. %x

I have tried option 2 (%x). And it works differently on 32 and 64 bit platforms. This resulted in inaccurate program behavior.

Now second option (%p) is also implementation defined.

So I would like to know which one should be used to have consistent behavior across all compilers and platforms.

Comment: Yes. `"%p"` is implementation specific, no guarantees. But more importantly, whatever you intend to do with that output, you will most likely not be able to do with it what you intend to do. I.e. I think we might be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please describe what you want to achieve by using the knowledge you ask for.

Comment: As already mentioned in question, I want to read an address from console and read it in a variable. This address is used for business specific purpose.

Comment: OK, I take that as a "I won't tell you." Please understand that this kind of answer reduces the helpful mood of many StackOverflow users, at least those like me. Good luck. Consider at least to specifiy more details of your environment. As already mentioned, the syntax is implementation and indirectly environment specific. You even tagged accordingly. So currently the answer is at least "It depends." it might be "I won't tell you."

Comment: Your title and question are a bit mismatched. In the title, you refer to `0x` format but, in the question body, you only say "won't work correctly". And your title uses "print" but your question refers to "sscanf". Can we have some clarity?

Comment: Improved the question. Thanks @Yunnosch for correcting me.

Comment: As you wrote about about "case [...] where `%p` won't work correctly" or "inaccurate program behavior" or "consistent behavior across all compilers and platforms", please specify in your question what you define as "working correctly" or "accurate behavior" and what "consistent behavior" is required for your use case.

Comment: Across **all** compilers and platforms? I think getting consistent results between 16-bit MS-DOS and 64-bit big-endian RISC may be a somewhat unrealistic goal.

Comment: Rather than `"%x"`, I would recommend `"%" SCNxPTR`, reading into a `uintptr_t`. (I assume you are only interested in systems using "flat" pointers, not "segmented" pointers.)

Comment: Hemant, "I want to read an address from console and read it in a variable" is the opposite problem of printing an address.  Do you need to print function pointers or just object ones? What is the specific goal, reading pointers, writing or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not guarantee any method of printing pointers is completely “consistent” across all implementations and cannot do so since pointers are inherently specific to memory models, which are not controlled by the C standard.

You can control some aspects of printing a pointer, such as ensuring it is always printed with hexadecimal, by converting it to `uintptr_t` and using the usual `printf` conversion controls:

```
#include <inttypes.h> // Define PRIxPTR.
#include <stdint.h>   // Define uintptr_t.
#include <stdio.h>    // Declare printf.

void PrintPointer(const volatile void *p)
{
    printf("0x%08" PRIxPTR, (uintptr_t) p);
}
```

This will ensure the pointer is printed using hexadecimal to represent its bits. The `uintptr_t` must contain sufficient information to reproduce the pointer value (or an equivalent), so the display will necessarily contain sufficient information about the pointer. However, the order and meaning of the bits is not defined by the C standard. The `08` guarantees at least eight digits are printed (with leading zeros as needed), which gives you some uniformity across mixed architectures of 32- and 64-bit pointers, but C implementations could use any number of bits, so a pointer could be printed with more digits. You could use just `"0x%"` if you do not consider fixing the number of digits to be part of the “consistent” formatting.

The `uintptr_t` type is optional but is likely to be provided in modern C implementations.

(The `const` and `volatile` qualifiers are irrelevant to the routine itself; they are included merely so that pointers with them, or without them, can be passed to the routine without complaint from the compiler.)

Comment: You can also cast the pointer to `size_t` and print that with `%zx`.

Comment: @icebp: The C standard does not guarantee that conversions to `size_t` preserve sufficient information about pointers. A C implementation may have a 16-bit `size_t` but require 22 bits to represent pointers.